# How to order list of string based on matching alphabets occurrence?

Tags: php, jquery, regex, sorting, preg-match

I am not sure if anyone else have faced this issue. 
I have an list of array elements which need to display on auto suggest. I biggest issue is I need to display all the categories based on matching string inside the category name.

For example -
If I type auto in search box it should display matching records on auto suggest like -

Indus -> **Auto**mation -> Contribution 
Construction -> **Auto**mation -> Industry 
Indus -> Es**auto**mation -> TNB 
Cal -> Thead**auto**->Textile

It should be order based on the matching alphabets. If first 3 chars matches from category it should display that category first then second occurrence and last occurrence so on. I am using regx in jquery to display matching string. I will prefer solution either in jquery else php.

It will be really helpful if I get some solution.

Comment: Can you include the code where your results are returned? You should be able to sort it on the index (position) of the matched string.

Comment: Can you share the structure of the given arrays and its elements?

Comment: If I type "ead" keyword then array form as below-<br>   Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [search_id] => 7878
            [searched_string] => Hydraulic Catheads
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [search_id] => 6711
            [searched_string] => Wellheads - Xmas Trees
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [search_id] => 7853
            [searched_string] => Lead
        )
    [3] => 
        (  
            [search_id] => 8853
            [searched_string] => Eads Company
        )   
 ) Eads company should display first

Answer (score 0):

I use this bound to keypress:

```
jQuery('select.myClass').find('option').hide();
jQuery('select.myClass').find('option:hidden[value*="' + searchFor + '"]').show();
```

Probably not the most efficient code in the world, but I run it against a bunch of selects, each containing upto several hundred options and not yet had a major performance issue.
The same will work for anything else since all it's doing is using jQuery's `*=` selector.

[Here for *= selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) or similarly [here for :contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

All you then need to do to achieve the correct ordering in jQuery is to pickup one of the many jQuery sort plugins (or use [native javascript sort function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp)) and sort with a function like this one:

```
var searchFor = 'foo';
function sortByPos(val1, val2)
{
  return (val1.indexOf(searchFor) > val2.indexOf(searchFor) ? +1 : -1);
}
```